# Pandas DataFrame TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a current project, I am planning to crawl over all CSV files within a given folder, to filter the content of the files by a certain word and to then save the filtered data frame as a new file with an extension that includes the search keyword.

The script below is however yielding the message `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` for line `df2 = df[df['tag'] == "Sales"]`, hence indicating an issue with the data type.

I have already tried to solve things by adding a generic data type definition such as `dtype='unicode'`, which did not solve things. Is there any smart tweak to make this work?

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob

# Crawl over all CSV files within folder
df = glob.glob(r'/Users/name/SEC/Merged/*.csv')

# Filter by key word "Sales"
df2 = df[df['tag'] == "Sales"]

# Remove duplicates
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=False)

# Save as new file that includes the name of the "input" file as well as the extension '-sales'.
df2.to_csv(basename+'-sales.csv')

# Sanity check print command
print(df2)
```

Comment: dont you have to read the csv using `pd.read_csv` to have it as dataframe? Right now df is just a list of paths which is of the datatype `str`.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Have you consulted the Pandas documentation? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Good point, thanks. I have added a line `df = (pd.read_csv(f, header = 0, dtype='unicode') for f in files)`. The script is now yielding for line `df2 = df[df['tag'] == "Sales"]` the following error:  `TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the paths and **read them into a dataframe**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob

# Crawl over all CSV files within folder
for csv_path in glob.glob(r'/Users/name/SEC/Merged/*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

    # Filter by key word "Sales"
    df2 = df[df['tag'] == "Sales"]

    # Remove duplicates
    df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=False)

    # Save as new file that includes the name of the "input" file as well as the extension '-sales'.
    df2.to_csv(csv_path+'-sales.csv')

    # Sanity check print command
    print(df2)
```